# Script for automation start and stop AWS EC2 instance

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudera-cdh

I've installed Cloudera cluster on 4 nodes Amazon EC2 instance.
For certain time such as Monday-Friday Night, Saturday, and Sunday, I didn't need to use those 4 nodes Amazon EC2 instance for more effective cost.

How to automate start and stop an those Amazon EC2 instances using script?
Could anybody give me the example of the script to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You can create script to stop and start instance(s) or directly run commands through [crontab](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm) in linux or [schedule-task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) in windows

for example if you want to stop instance at 11.00 pm
add below line in crontab (you will get this through crontab -e )

0 23 * * * sh stop.sh

format is
m h  dom mon dow   command

for start instance
`aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-1a1234`

for stop instance
`aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-1a1234`

Comment: Did you mean..                                                                                               0 2     * * *   lightstreamasia ec2-start-instances i-0bbd2c85
0 11    * * *  lightstreamasia ec2-stop-instances i-0bbd2c85

Answer (score 2):

I have written a small shell script to automate the starting and loggin in to my aws instances via terminal. You can use it

```
#!/bin/bash
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-070107834ab273992


public_ip=aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-070107834ab2 \
        --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicDnsName' --output text


AWS_KEY="/home/debian/cs605 data management/assignment6/mumbai instance keys"

ssh -v -i "$AWS_KEY"/mumbai-instance-1.pem\
        ec2-user@$public_ip
```

~
~